# Python, django: I made some codes but I think it takes time to perform. Is python slow? or my codes slow?

Tags: python, django

I would like to check and improve the codes I wrote because it takes time... slow

probably I could wrote better...

here are the codes at views.py

```
def price_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        flight_date = request.POST.get('flight_date')
        direction = request.POST.get('direction')
        suburb = request.POST.get('suburb')
        no_of_passenger = request.POST.get('no_of_passenger')

        def price_cal():
            if direction == 'Drop off To airport':
                return int(suburbs.get(suburb)) + ((int(no_of_passenger) * 10) - 10)
            else:
                return int(suburbs.get(suburb)) + (int(no_of_passenger) * 10)

        price_cal()
        price = str(price_cal())
        p = Post(flight_date=flight_date, direction=direction, suburb=suburb,
                 no_of_passenger=no_of_passenger, fare=price)
        p.save()

        data = {
            'flight_date': flight_date,
            'direction': direction,
            'suburb': suburb,
            'no_of_passenger': no_of_passenger,
            'price': price,

        }

        message = '''
                Flight date: {}
                Direction: {}        
                Suburb: {}
                No of passenger: {}
                Price: {}
                
                '''.format(data['flight_date'], data['direction'],
                           data['suburb'], data['no_of_passenger'], data['price'])
        send_mail(data['flight_date'], message, '', ['sungkam3@gmail.com'])

        return render(request, 'basecamp/price_detail.html',
                      {'flight_date': flight_date, 'direction': direction, 'suburb': suburb,
                       'no_of_passenger': no_of_passenger, 'price': price},
                      )

    else:
        return render(request, 'basecamp/price_detail.html', {})
```

User put some information on html and inquiry about the price... views get objects from templates, work out the price and after that, save all the information into database and email to me the details user inquiried. After all this donw, views.py send information to other page (html) to show the results to User.

it works fine... but the problem is only time... too slow

Is it because of Python or my codes?

Comment: How long is it taking?

Comment: Please profile your code and tell us what exactly is slow!

Comment: Move mailing to celery task, to confirm this, comment out sending mail, your code will be awesome quick. https://medium.com/@juwelariful1/send-mail-in-django-with-gmail-and-smtp-include-celery-and-gmail-configuration-4b07ae4f8542

Comment: it takes about 5 - 7 secs

Answer (score 2):

your code is fine, the problem is with sending an email, sending in an email could take a lot of time.

so you could refactor your code to send the email in a different thread or you could even use celery.

Comment: okay thanks. actually I was thinking of that too because I wanted to do schedule task (emailing)

Comment: my os is window... window is not doing well with rabbitMQ... I have to test and make sure everything is okay before putting it on hosting server but the problem is rabbitMQ....

Comment: you could use this service during development https://www.cloudamqp.com/